# window.onload Not Triggering in Injected Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, code-injection, onload

I have a chrome extension that injects javascript code into a webpage like so

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    const html = `
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(location.href);

            function doStuff() {
                console.log("do stuff");
            }

            console.log("onload");

            window.onload = function () {
                console.log("WINDOW LOADED");
                doStuff();
            }
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
    `;
    document.write(html);
}
```

However, after I navigate to the page and the extension injects the javascript, I can see in the console that it does log `location.href` and `onload`, but the `window.onload` does not trigger, and I do not see `WINDOW LOADED` in the console, nor is `doStuff()` called.

I have also tried using

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
});
```

as well as

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', doStuff);
```

to no avail.
Any help would be appreciated, I have not been able to find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by including at the top of my `<script>`

```
setTimeout(() => {
    let evt = document.createEvent('Event');
    evt.initEvent('load', false, false);
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
}, 300);
```

And this now causes `window.onload` to trigger. hope this helps anyone with the same issue

Comment: sounds like if you need this then your code is actually injected after page load...